# Move binary to local repository after Build Binary in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm building an R package using RStudio for my colleagues and have created a repository on a network drive for the package. So when I `build binary` in RStudio, the binary goes into my working directory.

How can I automate the following...

1. Move my binary into the repo folder
2. Run `tools::write_PACKAGES` in the repo folder

Is the best way to do this to write a script that does all of that and gets run by RStudio in the `Build Binary Package - R CMD INSTALL additional options`?

If not, what should I do to streamline it?

[image: RStudio]

Answer (score 1):

The relevant section in the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Building-binary-packages) handbook states

> To prevent changes to the present working installation or to provide an install location with write access, create a suitably located directory with write access and use the -l option to build the package in the chosen location. The usage is then
>
> ```
> R CMD INSTALL -l location --build pkg
> ```

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? Thanks! So that takes care of putting the binary in the right place. What about executing `tools::write_PACKAGES` on the repo folder? Can I  get R CMD INSTALL to run a script? (I wasn't able to find options for that)

Comment: (where the script contains `tools::write_PACKAGES(dir = "X:/R/bin/windows/contrib/2.15", type = "win.binary")`)

Comment: you could try `; Rscript -e tools::write_PACKAGES(dir = "X:/R/bin/windows/contrib/2.15", type = "win.binary"))` -- I'm not sure how Rstudio will add the command arguments -- but if that doesn't work, I'd put in a feature request to R studio to allow such a funtion.

Comment: Sadly, it seems that `-l` is for `library` and not `location`, so I'll have to do something else.

Comment: And the `;` trick for a running a script doesn't seem to work. Back to square one!